# Obtener un array ordenado con subtotales por fechas

Tags: laravel, eloquent

estoy necesitando resolver un problema que no le estoy encontrando la vuelta, soy bastante nuevo en laravel y php. La cosa es que tengo una colleccion con datos obtenidos de una base, con datos como fecha e importe y necesito darle una salida como array subtotalizando por fecha.

```
$movimientos = \App\Model\MovimientoCaja::where('caja_id', $data["caja_id"])->where('fecha', '>=', $data['fecha_inicio'])->where('fecha','<=', $data['fecha_fin'])->orderBy('fecha', 'ASC')->get();
```

Así obtengo la colleción, necesito trabajar eso para devolver un array donde tenga subtotalizado los importes por días

```html
$resultado = [ 
'17/12/2019': 
['importe' => 100, 'fecha' => 17/12/2019 08:44:00], 
['importe' => 100, 'fecha' => 17/12/2019 08:50:00], 
['subtotal' => '200', 'fecha' => 17/12/2019 08:50:00], 
'18/12/2019': 
['importe' => 100, 'fecha' => 18/12/2019 08:44:00], 
['importe' => 100, 'fecha' => 18/12/2019 08:50:00], 
['subtotal' => '200', 'fecha' => 18/12/2019 08:50:00], ];
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Si pudieras colocar un ejemplo de la salida que esperas nos ayudaría mucho a entender mejor el problema.

Comment: Hola no me percate de eso, la idea sería obtener un array o coleccion donde por día tenga un subtotal. Ahora pongo un ejemplo de salida

Comment: Edita la pregunta con un ejemplo, aunque lo hice así nomas es algo así la idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongamos que de una query simple de una tabla de pedidos

```
 $data = Pedido::select(['created_at', 'precio_total'])
        ->where('precio_total', '>', 0)
        ->take(8)
        ->get();
```

Salen registros como

```
[
    ['created_at'=> "2019-08-06 16:55:30", 'precio_total'=> 1500],
    ['created_at'=> "2019-08-07 19:17:10", 'precio_total'=> 13990],
    ['created_at'=> "2019-08-07 19:39:56", 'precio_total'=> 13990],
    ['created_at'=> "2019-08-07 20:45:30", 'precio_total'=> 4790],
    ['created_at'=> "2019-08-11 23:26:41", 'precio_total'=> 8990],
    ['created_at'=> "2019-08-12 18:34:28", 'precio_total'=> 16990],
    ['created_at'=> "2019-08-12 18:58:09", 'precio_total'=> 16990],
    ['created_at'=> "2019-08-12 19:08:28", 'precio_total'=> 16990]
]
```

`$data` es una instancia de  [Illuminate\Support\Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections). Tú podrías transformar esa colección usando el método  [reduce](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-reduce), que permite iterar los registros y meterlos a un acumulador (igual que array_reduce nativo de PHP). Esto se hace más o menos así:

```
  $data = $data->reduce(function ($accum, $record) {
        $fecha = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($record->created_at));
        if (!array_key_exists($fecha, $accum)) {
            $accum[$fecha] = [['subtotal' => 0, 'fecha' => $fecha]];
        }
        $accum[$fecha][] = $record->toArray();
        $accum[$fecha][0]['subtotal'] += $record->precio_total;
        return $accum;
    }, []);
```

Fíjate que al usar `reduce` necesito una referencia en donde ir acumulando el subtotal diario. En esta implementación yo digo que el primer elemento del array que representa los pedidos del día es el que corresponde al subtotal, y por eso digo:

```
// Fecha del registro  
$fecha = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($record->created_at));

// Si no existe la fecha de este registro en el acumulador
if (!array_key_exists($fecha, $accum)) {
   // inicializo esa fecha con el subtotal como elemento cero
   $accum[$fecha] = [['subtotal' => 0, 'fecha' => $fecha]];
}
// Los elementos de esta fecha se van añadiendo al acumulador
$accum[$fecha][] = $record->toArray();

// Y el subtotal de ese día se incrementa en el monto de cada registro
$accum[$fecha][0]['subtotal'] += $record->precio_total;
```

El resultado final es:

```
[
 "2019-08-06": [
    {
      "subtotal": 1500,
      "fecha": "2019-08-06"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2019-08-06 16:55:30",
      "precio_total": 1500
    }
  ],
  "2019-08-07": [
    {
      "subtotal": 32770,
      "fecha": "2019-08-07"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2019-08-07 19:17:10",
      "precio_total": 13990
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2019-08-07 19:39:56",
      "precio_total": 13990
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2019-08-07 20:45:30",
      "precio_total": 4790
    }
  ],
  "2019-08-11": [
    {
      "subtotal": 8990,
      "fecha": "2019-08-11"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2019-08-11 23:26:41",
      "precio_total": 8990
    }
  ],
  "2019-08-12": [
    {
      "subtotal": 50970,
      "fecha": "2019-08-12"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2019-08-12 18:34:28",
      "precio_total": 16990
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2019-08-12 18:58:09",
      "precio_total": 16990
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2019-08-12 19:08:28",
      "precio_total": 16990
    }
  ]
 ]
```